# Can I use Spell Accuracy on a Wall of Fire?

Tags: dnd-4e, wizard, wall

The epic level feat **Spell Accuracy** from the PHB says:

> Benefit: You can omit a number of
>   squares from the  area of effect of
>   any of your area or close wizard
>   powers.  This number can’t exceed your
>   Wisdom modifier.

*Wall* is defined under "Areas of Effect" on page 272 of the PHB along with bursts and blasts, but it carries the following condition:

> Each square of the wall must share a
>   side—not just  a corner—with at least
>   one other square of the wall...

Does the feat override that requirement for the wall?

For example, say I have a Wisdom modifier of +3. Can I use **Spell Accuracy** to create a 3 square gap in the middle of my 8 square long **Wall of Fire** so I don't kill the unconscious, dying paladin in the middle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would rule that yes, you could create the gap. But the squares in the gap would count towards your eight total squares of wall.

The way I interpret the feat to work:

- Determine the area of effect for the spell.
- Choose squares to omit.
- Apply damage to all squares that haven't been omitted.

In your example, you would create a valid eight-square wall of fire directly over the paladin. You would then omit the paladin's square and the two adjacent squares.

Disclaimer: I don't have any citations on this one. It's purely my interpretation of the wording of the feat.

Comment: I agree with this one.  I believe it's a case of "specific overrides general" which is explicitly stated as a rule in PHB1.